# Конвертирование строки в числовое выражение

Tags: строки, ruby, числа, конвертация

Есть строка вида: `"5 + 5"`

Необходимо из нее, получить числовое выражение вида: 5 + 5

Пробовал через .to_i, в итоге не вышло:

```
"5 + 5".to_i
 => 5
```

Вопрос: Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Вариант первый, безопасный

Вам нужно использовать парсер математических выражений.  Можно
использовать готовый, типа
https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku,
а можно написать свой.  См., напрмер, классику: “[*Let's Build
A Compiler*](https://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/)” Джека Креншоу (англ. *Jack Crenshaw*).  Там
паскаль, но на руби будет перевести легко.

#### Вариант второй, опасный(!)

Если вы **целиком и полностью доверяете** источнку данных,
вы можете использовать метод `eval`:

```ruby
puts(eval("5 + 5"))
# Output:
#   10
```

Это даёт вашему источнику данных возможность выполнять
**любой** код, включая
`rm -rf --no-preserve-root /`.

Comment: при использовании `eval` лучше проверить для начала содержание строки, например как-то так: `/^[\d\s\+\-\*\/]+$/.match?("5 + 5")`